# sim1000G simulation error in genetic map: mismatch between chromosomes in genetic map and vcf

Tags: r, generics, simulation

I'm currently trying to simulate the genotypes of 3 different genes from different chromosomes using sim1000G package in R this is my code

This is my code to get the SNPs for the specific region of the gene:

```
tabix - h ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk       /vol1/ftp/release/20100804/ALL.2of4intersection.20100804.genotypes.vcf.gz 18:52340197-53535899 > DCC.vcf
```

this is my function to get the genotypes:

```
get_genotype=function(vcf_path){
  vcf = readVCF( vcf_path ,min_maf = NA, max_maf = NA,maxNumberOfVariants = 7000)
  startSimulation(vcf, totalNumberOfIndividuals = 3010)
  ids = generateUnrelatedIndividuals(3000)
  genotype = retrieveGenotypes(ids)
  return(genotype)
  
}
```

I run it on the first gene  and it went very well :

```
 genotype_sorcs=get_genotype("SORCS3.vcf")
```

But then when i want to simulate for another gene i ger this error:

```
genotypr_linc=get_genotype("5-88507546-88691057_snps.vcf") [#.......] 
Reading VCF file.. Rows: 1189 Columns: 638  Column specification  Delimiter: "\t" chr (636): ID, REF, ALT,
  QUAL, FILTER, INFO, FORMAT, HG00098, HG00100, HG00106, HG00112, HG00114, HG0... dbl  (2): #CHROM, POS
    Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.  Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = 
   FALSE` to quiet this message. [##......] Chromosome:   5  Mbp:  88.50758  Region Size:  183.224 kb  Num of 
  individuals: 629  [##......] Before filtering  Num of variants: 1189 Num of individuals: 629  [###.....] After filtering  Num of 
  variants: 1189 Num of individuals: 629  [#####...] Creating SIM object [#####...] Haplodata object created 10 5  Error in 
  startSimulation(vcf, totalNumberOfIndividuals = 3010) :    Error: mismatch between chromosomes in genetic map and vcf  
 In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

I tried to add

```
resetSimulation()
```

between the simulations  for different genes but it didn't  solve the problem
would be happy to know what is happening and how can i fix this (when i simulate each gene independently after deleting the environment in R for the previous simulation it works but when i want to simulate one after another it fails ), thank you